# Presence of accents in sections, chapters etc.

Tags: accents

i would like to know how can i put labels and names of sections and chapters using accents. I get errors when i try

```
\chapter{Conclusión}
como se menciona en \ref{algo}.
\section{Other seccion name with áccent}
\label{algo}
```

Comment: Do accents work properly anywhere else? And yes, you really should provide a complete (preferably small) example: see the [question on minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/1189) on meta.

Comment: Using `xelatex` instead of `latex`/`pdflatex` (and making sure your input is saved as Unicode UTF-8) makes a lot of these character-encoding problems go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we need a *complete* example with an error description ...
This works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Conclusión}
como se menciona en \ref{algo}.
\section{Other seccion name with áccent}\label{algo}

\end{document}
```